# Monitor Java 8 ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Is there a way to monitor what [Java ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) is doing over time, particularly how effeciently [CountedCompleter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountedCompleter.html) performs ?

- How much time did subtasks take to execute ?
- Was one of the subtasks longer than the others ?
- Did they execute in parallel ?

Applied to the example of triggers in CountedCompleter javadoc, the monitoring tool would tell me that `PacketSender` completion was limited by `HeaderBuilder` which started first but took 13s while `BodyBuilder` took 4s and completed before.

I look for such a tool, mostly as a Java agent not to pollute my production code with unnecessary statistics, but found nothing.

Thanks for any help

Comment: good question as far as I can tell, they had to use something internally to test this...

Comment: Hello @Eugene, yes, this is what I think too. Let's see

Comment: Aleksey Shipilëv (https://shipilev.net/) did a benchmark on the FJP for Java7. The results were awful as I remember. I did not see a benchmark for Java8. In order to monitor the FJ Classes you would need to extract the source from the zip file and add your own code to keep track of things. A lot of work as the FJ Classes only concentrate on doing work, not on giving statistics.

Comment: Hello @edharned, I was not aware of that benchmark (post a link ?) but that's not really the question here.
To avoid extracting classes from the sources, I plan to use the instrumentation API natively in the JDK, to add some statistics. This way, code remains focused doing work :)

Comment: OK. You can use visualVM to look at the heavily used classes. Other than that you can always build your own. But, and it's a big, but, I don't see how you are going to answer those three questions with instrumentation alone.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and realistically only) way is to use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to "spy" on method calls and record start and end timestamps and context that can be collected for statistical analysis.

I have used [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) to good effect and can recommend it, but any such library should work.

Comment: Hello Bohemian, so far, I managed to gather various statistics by creating a java agent using javassist to capture start and end of computations. My problem was now to export it correctly, as I was printing stats in stdout, generating too much data. I will look at AspectJ as well.